# Outlook 2016 Windows - Quick add contact fields

Tags: microsoft-outlook, contacts, microsoft-outlook-2016

Outlook 2016 (Windows) has a feature that allows you to hover over a person's name and quickly add them to your address book.

The problem is that the default fields are virtually useless, and for whatever reason, Microsoft did not think it would be necessary to include *Company Name* as a standard field.

Are these fields customizable in some way ? Or is there any way to add *Company* and *Title* to the default list shown below?

[image: Outlook Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is way that you can add company name and title. Click the + icon in work and you will see it.